# How to select all text in a UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a small project where people can create items to be shown on a list, and when they first create an item, it get a generic name: "New Item", so I wanted the app to know to select the whole title in order to make it easier for the user to rename it. I went online and spent a good long time searching for a way to do it, but every way I tried went wrong. This was the last thing I've done, and what this part of my code looks like:

```
if ([self.detailItem.title isEqualToString:@"New Item"]) {

    self.titleField.selectedTextRange = nil;
}
```

But I've also tried `[self.titleField selectAll:self]` but it didn't work either, neither, as I've said, did anything else I've tried.

Any ideas on what I should do?

If you need anymore code just let me know what part of it and I'll edit it into this question.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you thought about using a placeholder text?

Comment: How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: UITextField *textField;
textField.placeholder = @"my placeholder text";

Comment: That did solve it for me, thanks for the idea, I don't know why I hadn't thought of it

Comment: Accept the answer please. I'm glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 30)];
[self.view addSubview:textField];
textField.placeholder = @"my placeholder text";
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple set the selected range appropriately:

```
if ([self.detailItem.title isEqualToString:@"New Item"]) {

    self.titleField.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, self.titleField.text.length);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me:

```
- (void)selectAllTextInField:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITextPosition  *theStart   = [textField beginningOfDocument];
    UITextPosition  *theEnd     = [textField endOfDocument];
    UITextRange     *theRange   = [textField textRangeFromPosition:theStart toPosition:theEnd];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:theRange];
}
```